# How to mock "localforage" in angular jasmine unit test cases

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, mocking, localforage

I'm using the localforage to store the session in the client side. I'm trying write the unit test cases for the methods of my angular service, How do I stub or mock the localforage. Please help.

I've

```
import { Injectable } from ‘@angular/core’;
@Injectable()
export class TokenService {
  private TOKEN_KEY = ‘id_token’;
  constructor() { }
  setAccessToken(token: string) {
    localForage.setItem(this.TOKEN_KEY, token);
  }
  getAccessToken(): string {
    return localForage.getItem(this.TOKEN_KEY);
  }
}
```

I'm looking for the way to not to call the actual localforage methods as my intention is not to test the library. Piece of working is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the test module to inject a spy object when a component is asking for a `TockenService`.

This can be done by defining the service with the `useValue` property in your providers definition `[{ provide: TockenService, useValue: mockTokenService  }]`.

```
describe('YourComponent', () => {
  let component: YourComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<YourComponent>;

  let mockTokenService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    mockTokenService  = jasmine.createSpyObj(['setAccessToken', 'getAccessToken']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [YourComponent],
      imports: [],
      providers: [{ provide: TockenService, useValue: mockTokenService  }]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    mockTokenService.getAccessToken.and.returnValue('YOURTOKENSTRING');

    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```